# letting a DLL call a exe function with function pointer

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?
I'm trying to run a custom main on a different thread.

This is the code.

**.exe**
main.cpp

```
#include "dll_class.h"
#include <iostream>
int main(void);
DllClass object(main);
int main(void)
{
    std::cout << "Enter the main code.\n";
    std::getchar();
}
```

**.dll**
dll_class.h

```
#include "platform.h"
#include <iostream>
class DLL_API DllClass //DLL_API is just a macro for import and export.
{
public:
    DllClass(int(*main)(void))
    {
        std::cout << "Start application.\n";
        platform = new Platform(main);
    }
    ~DllClass(void)
    {
        delete platform;
    }
private:
    Platform* platform;
};
```

platform.h

```
class DLL_API Platform
{
public:
    Platform(main_t main_tp);
    ~Platform(void){}
};
```

platform.cpp

```
#include "platform.h"
#include "Windows.h"
#include <iostream>

HHOOK hookHandle;
int(*main_p)(void);//This will hold a the main function of the the .exe.
LRESULT CALLBACK keyHandler(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

DWORD WINAPI callMain(_In_  LPVOID lpParameter)
{
    std::cout << "Calling the main function.\n";
    main_p();
    return 0;
}

Platform::Platform(int(*main_tp)(void))
{
    main_p = main_tp;
    CreateThread(NULL, 0, callMain, NULL, 0, NULL);
    std::cout << "Setting hooks.\n";
    hookHandle = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, keyHandler, NULL, 0);
    std::cout << "Enter message loop.\n";
    MSG message;
    while(GetMessage(&message, (HWND)-1, 0, 0) != 0){
        TranslateMessage( &message );
        DispatchMessage( &message );
    }
}

LRESULT CALLBACK keyHandler(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    std::cout << "Inside the hook function.\n" << std::endl;
    return CallNextHookEx(hookHandle, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

It runs great, till a certain moment.
This is the output.

```
Start application.  
Setting hooks.  
Calling the main function.  
Enter message loop.  
Inside the hook function. (A lot of times of course).
```

but it never says:

```
Enter the main code.
```

Is it impossible to let dll call a exe function?

Comment: Your Platform constructor has not yet returned. `main` cannot run until objects are constructed, and your constructor hasn't finished yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very much POSSIBLE to call a function in the executable file from a shared library. However, the C standard, as mentioned in the other answer, doesn't allow you to call `main`. This has to do with the fact that the C runtime [to guard against language lawyers: insert "sometimes" here] relies on a certain order of things, and if you try to call `main` before the C runtime has done the right initialization BEFORE `main`, you get problems.

If your goal is to actually subvert what `main` does, then you will have to find a different way of achieving this - at least if you expect it to work for more than one particular executable.

Comment: I think that is a completely different question - and I'm not entirely sure I a) understand the question completely or b) know the answer to it. Obviously, when producing something like .NET, it's quite a complex process, and I can't say I actually know what it does... The .NET "starting process" is quite likely a wrapper for something else - but that's a guess, not knowledge.

Comment: Sorry my question wasn't finished. Somehow he posted it.

Comment: Thank, I'm trying to create a layer around WinAPI and .NET. I noticed when the main of a .NET application returns, it goes further in lower levels. The main is a thread itself, isn't it? I was trying to create that same effect. I want to make sure the hooks are set and the message loop is running before the user calls main. Is there an alternative. If I create a custom main like `my_main` can I make sure they don't have to call both main and `my_main`?

Comment: In a C or C++ program, you MUST call `main` if you want to use any of the services provided by the C/C++ runtime library [of course, there may be some functions that work without it, but you are in "undefined behaviour land" if you do that]. If you are building your own runtime for a different language, and not using the normal C runtime functionality [and I expect .NET does this] then that's no big deal. But if you expect regular C or C++ code to work, forget it.

Answer (score 1):

The C++ standard doesn't allow calling main() or taking its address, which is what you're doing here. See [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/55784/) thread which quotes line and verse. So, what you're doing is undefined.